# Append messages different color in log_console

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can somebody help me with JavaScript. I have log console

```
<div id="log_console"></div>
```

and I need to write function which has two parameters `type = {success, error}` and `text ="some text"`. I need to show each message in separated line , **blue** if success, **red** if error.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. In what browser(s) do you want this?

Comment: @Jana - it's not clear if your console is a DOM element or if you are referring to a developer console. The code in the OP was added by @Balanivash

Comment: @adam : actually I dint add it. It was in the OP and as it was not within backticks it was not visible earlier.

Comment: What a mess - the history was not clear on who added what :(

Comment: Ah, I see - it also wasn't shown in the edit history

Answer (score 1):

```
function log(type, text) {
    var colour = (type = 'success') ? 'blue', 'red';
    $('<p />').css('color', colour).html(text).appendTo($('#log_console'));
}
```

Comment: Nice, `color` vs `colour` in the same line. Even if you are British (too lazy to check your profile) - in such a case it would make more sense to use the same spelling like internally, i.e. `color`

Comment: Was there really any need for an insult? Regardless of variable names, the code demonstrates a solution in a concise way

Comment: How was that an insult? IMO it was a pretty neutral comment. The "if you are british" part was meant like "it might be natural for you to write colour instad of color"

Answer (score 0):

This function called onclick event should do the trick:

```
function appendToLog( type, text )
{
    var myLogDiv = document.getElementById("log_console");

    var myText = document.createTextNode(text + "<br/>");
    var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
    if(type=="error")
    {
        myDiv.style.color = "red";
    }
    else
    {
        myDiv.style.color = "blue";
    }

    myDiv.appendchild( myText );
    myLogDiv.appendChild( myDiv );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_message(type, text) {
    var color;
    switch(type) {
        case "success":
            color = "blue";
            break;
        case "error":
            color = "red";
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
    var new_div = $("", { 'html': text, 'css': { 'color': color } });
    $("#log_console").append(new_div);
}
```

You can play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/NdWZr/